# Retorno de uma busca binária

Tags: c, busca-binária

Tenho a seguinte questão:

> Desenvolver uma função recursiva que encontra um valor em um vetor ordenado utilizando busca binária. A função deve dar como resposta a posição do valor do vetor. Se o valor não estiver no vetor, retorna -1.

Daí eu desenvolvi o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BuscaBinaria(int[] v, int inicio, int fim, int valor) {
    int meio;
    meio=(inicio+fim)/2;
    if(meio>valor)
    {
        return BuscaBinaria(v, inicio, meio-1, valor);
    }
    if(meio<valor)
    {
        return BuscaBinaria(v, inicio+1, meio, valor);
    }
    if(meio==valor)
    {
        return meio;
    }
    else {
    return -1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int tam, valor;
    int k;
    printf("Qual o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    int v[tam], i;
    printf("Informe os valores do vetor:\n");
    for(i=1; i<=tam; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    printf("Informe o numero a ser buscado: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    k= BuscaBinaria(v,1,tam,valor);
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

Mas quando o valor não está dentro do vetor, o programa dá erro. Ele para e retorna um número qualquer no final. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Poste o código como texto mesmo para facilitar para as pessoas ajudarem.

Comment: Leia isso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/132

Comment: Lembre-se que em C os arrays iniciam na posição 0, e não na posição 1.

Comment: Ah, a formatação do site reconhece como código-fonte linhas iniciadas por 4 espaços. Assim sendo, coloque 4 espaços no início de cada linha do seu código e poste. Uma outra alternativa é postar o seu código todo, selecioná-lo e então clicar no botão `{}` que aparece na sua barra de edição.

Answer (score 2):

O seu código tem vários problemas.

Primeiro que você faz verificações tais como `(meio>valor)` ao invés de `(v[meio]>valor)`. Isso é importante, pois se você notar bem, em momento nenhum da sua busca binária você está acessando os elementos do array, logo, não teria como funcionar.

Além disso, o critério em que vai retornar -1 é quando `fim` for igual a `inicio` sem que o elemento procurado esteja nessa posição. Do jeito que você colocou, ele nunca retornaria -1, uma vez que quaisquer que sejam os valores de `meio` e `valor`, não há como todas as condições `meio>valor`, `meio<valor` e `meio==valor` serem todas falsas ao mesmo tempo.

No `main`, você está iterando e acessando as posições do array de 1 até `tam`. Ocorre que em C o primeiro elemento está na posição 0, e portanto o último está na posição `tam - 1`.

Ah, e por favor, pelo amor de Deus, não poste código em formato de imagem. Todo mundo nessa comunidade odeia muito isso. Código como imagem é difícil porque não dá para copiar e colar e sair alterando para poder formular uma resposta. Eu por exemplo tive que me dar ao trabalho de redigitar o seu código inteiro antes de postar essa resposta, trabalho esse que poucas pessoas dispostas a responder se sujeitariam a ter.

Com todas essas mudanças, o seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BuscaBinaria(int v[], int inicio, int fim, int valor) {
    int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;
    if (v[meio] == valor) return meio;
    if (fim == inicio) return -1;
    if (v[meio] > valor) return BuscaBinaria(v, inicio, meio - 1, valor);
    return BuscaBinaria(v, inicio + 1, meio, valor);
}

int main() {
    int tam, valor;
    printf("Qual o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    int v[tam], i;
    printf("Informe os valores do vetor:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    printf("Informe o numero a ser buscado: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    int k = BuscaBinaria(v, 0, tam - 1, valor);
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/ugWXwl)