# O que acontece se uma busca binária não acha o elemento?

Tags: java, array, algoritmo, busca-binária

O que acontece se uma busca binária não acha o elemento? Ele entra em *loop*? 
Qual é a melhor forma de terminar a execução?

Comment: Precisa indicar que não encontrou o elemento. Tipo o mesmo retorno de "código de erro" usado na busca linear.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167105/64969

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que acontece se uma busca binária não acha o elemento?

Encerra a busca sem achar o elemento. Nada mais que isso. Lógica pura.

> Ele entra em *loop*?

Por que faria isso? Uma busca binária vai analisando os elementos sempre na metade anterior ou posterior ao último elemento analisado, rapidinho a metade chega ter tamanho de um elemento e não tem mais o que verificar. Mesmo que tenha 1 bilhão de elementos só precisará 30 análises. Justamente se chegar no ponto de não ter mais o que verificar e não deu igualdade em nenhuma análise então não achou o elemento procurado.

> Qual é a melhor forma de terminar a execução?

Não tem a melhor forma, pelo menos no geral, pode ter em detalhes. O encerramento deve ocorrer assim que achar o elemento ou não ter mais elementos para analisar, o que acontecer primeiro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).